# Подключение smb python

Tags: python

Пытаюсь подключиться к удаленному компьютеру и вывести список файлов в шаре с помощью библиотеки pysmb, ниже код

```
from smb.SMBConnection import SMBConnection    
userID = "ldaprader"
    password = "######"
    client_machine_name = "zabbix-srv"
    remote_machine_name = "Swiftbis"
    server_ip = "192.168.133.2"
    conn = SMBConnection(userID, password, client_machine_name, remote_machine_name, use_ntlm_v2 = True)
    conn.connect(server_ip, 445)
    filelist = conn.listPath('dhcp$', '/')
```

Получаю ошибку

```
File "/root/mac6/txt.py", line 9, in <module>
    conn.connect(server_ip, 445)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/smb/SMBConnection.py", line 127, in connect
    self._pollForNetBIOSPacket(timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/smb/SMBConnection.py", line 613, in _pollForNetBIOSPacket
    raise ex
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/smb/SMBConnection.py", line 602, in _pollForNetBIOSPacket
    d = self.sock.recv(read_len)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

Что делаю не так?

Comment: соединение сбрасывается. Проверьте на всякий случай ещё раз адрес, порт, логин и пароль

Answer (score 0, accepted):

у меня получилось подключится по порту 139